# MariaDB - GRANT SELECT ON `DBX`.* TO `admin`@`172.22.%.%` WITH GRANT OPTION - from remote HOST fails

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-grant

I've two ubuntu host, host01 is the DB Server in host02, and I need to install a PHP Application.
Both hosts are in the same network (172.22)
The installation process requires a user with administrative rights to:

1. create a database (DBX)
2. assign grants to the database, for a user.

I've added manually the user (admin) in MariaDB in this way:

- CREATE USER 'admin'@'172.22.%.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxxxxxx';

I have no issue to create the database from host02, but when I try to run the following SQL

- GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT ON `DBX`.* TO 'admin'@'172.22.%.%';

I'm always getting:
Access denied for user 'admin'@'172.22.%.%' to database 'DBX'

The issue happens when the query is run from the PHP Application, and also if I use the mariadb client from host02, then it seems not related to PHP.

Any idea?

Comment: Does your user have administrator permissions?

Comment: You can check your own privileges with `SHOW GRANTS;` if you _don't_ have the `WITH GRANT OPTION` yourself, then you cannot grant privileges to other users. It may seem counter-intuitive that you can create the database, and you can create the user, but you still cannot grant privileges on that database to that user.

Comment: @Bill Karwin
Thanks a lot, I've just done a test checking that SHOW GRANTS displays WITH GRANT OPTION, and everything now seems to work as expected